# Embed external page within you view as partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails application running on port 3000 and have another Java web application running on 5000. 
Based on the inputs provided, the rails application generates a dynamic link clicking on which redirects you to the application running on port 5000. 
I was wondering, if there is any way so that rather than redirecting to 2nd application, I can render a view with contents from the second application embedded within it. 
Is it possible? 
**Update**: Java application is producing flash based content for browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the possiblities:

- You can use an `iframe` but many people don't want this.
- You can download the content of your Java server and include that in the view. But that would increase the total loading time and is not what I'd call clean either.
- Dump your Java or Ruby on Rails application and solve it just with Java or Ruby on Rails.

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I forgot to mention that the Java application is producing flash based content for browser. Your  3rd option is not feasible for us. But, I'll definitely check 1st and 2nd options.